# How to set Marker icon using fontawesome

Tags: android, google-maps, bitmap, drawable

```
Drawable iconmarker = FontIconDrawable.inflate(context, R.xml.ic_red_marker);

Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) iconmarker).getBitmap();


driver_marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(latLng)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap)));*/
```

ic_red_marker.xml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 ----  font-icon
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:text="@string/icon_marker"
    android:textSize="@dimen/icon_size"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
```

font-awesome code

```
<string name="icon_marker">&#xf041;</string>
```

**ERROR**

> line- Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) iconmarker).getBitmap();
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.shamanland.fonticon.FontIconDrawable cannot be cast to
>   android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable

Comment: You are going to need to render the `Drawable` to your own `Bitmap`-backed `Canvas`, or find some other way to get something that `icon()` will accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set IconDrawable as below :

```
IconDrawable drawable =  new IconDrawable(this, IconValue.fa_home).colorRes(R.color.ab_item)
                        .actionBarSize())
```

Now you can set **IconDrawable to Imageview** like below :

```
imageview.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

And now if you want bitmap then try

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
```

For this you need to add android-iconify jar to your libs folder.

Reference :

1) https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-iconify

2) http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadandroidiconifysample101jar.htm

Hope it will help you.

Comment: IconDrawable and IconValue- for there class have any lib or i have to create custome?

Comment: yes.. For that you need to add android-iconify jar in your libs folder.

Comment: Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap(); inconvertable type from icondrawablw to bitmapdrawable.

Comment: BitmapDescriptor customMarker = getCustomMarker("\uf041"); am getting error on this line. http://paste.ofcode.org/YqscXGGbWPN7NZN57sqCgF

Comment: What error you are getting, can you please explain ?